# SQL Constraints are not running in Odoo 11

Tags: python, constraints, odoo, odoo-11

## Problem

I have the following model `myModel`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from odoo import models, fields, api

class myModel(models.Model):
    _name = 'myproject.myModel'

    name= fields.Char('Name', size=9, required=True)
    startDate = fields.Datetime('Start date',required=True)
    endDate= fields.Datetime('End date',required=True)

    _sql_constraints = [('date_constraint', 'CHECK((endDate > startDate))', 'End date must be later than start date')]
```

The problem is that the sql constraints are not making anything. I have tried:

- Not using demo data.
- Update module
- Full restart Odoo (postgresql included)
- Use New database
- Also I tried with other _sql_constraints like: `_sql_constraints = [('name_constraint', 'UNIQUE((name))', 'Name must be unique.')]`

## Solution

> The problem was that the field contained uppercase and it seems that
>   the sql_constraint converts everything to lowercase, so that field was
>   not found in the database. So I convert startDate to startdate and
>   endDate to enddate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome! Thanks for posting a good question with all needed details.

You need to update the addon.

If still it doesn't work, check the logs. Odod will fail to install a SQL constraint if any preexisting record violates it. In such case, it will log a WARNING. Delete or fix that record and upgrade the module again.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for responding I have managed to fix it. The problem was that in my real project the field contained uppercase and it seems that the sql_constraint converts everything to lowercase, so that field was not found in the database. I give your answer valid, since it is another way to fix problems in sql_constraint. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

another possible solution to avoid change the fields names, "" the field name, I tested in "unique" case

```
_sql_constraints = [('date_constraint', 'CHECK(("endDate" > "startDate"))', 'End date must be later than start date')]
```